# c# how do Ikeep my radio button selection after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radio-button, postback

This is how my gridview looks like :

Basically , I select "you" as the correct answer .

[image]

But after I click the "+" button , the selection of radio button got removed .
[image]

How do I keep my selection of radio button for every row of gridview?

This is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
         SetInitialRow();
         dropActivity(); // ignore this , this is for drop down list
         dropTask();  // ignore this , this is for drop down list

     }
 }

private void SetInitialRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Question", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hints No.1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hints No.2", typeof(string)));

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Question"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Hints No.1"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Hints No.2"] = string.Empty;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //Store the DataTable in ViewState
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Question"] = box1.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Hints No.1"] = box2.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Hints No.2"] = box3.Text;

                rowIndex++;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    //  Set Previous Data on Postbacks
    SetPreviousData();
}

private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                RadioButton radiobtn1 = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("RadioButton1");
                RadioButton radiobtn2 = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("RadioButton2");

                //Setting previous text to the respective textboxes based on columns.
                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Question"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Hints No.1"].ToString();
                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Hints No.2"].ToString();

                if (radiobtn1.Checked == true)
                {
                    ViewState["RadioButtonStatus"] = radiobtn1.Checked;
                }

                if (radiobtn2.Checked == true)
                {
                    ViewState["RadioButtonStatus"] = radiobtn2.Checked;
                }

                Session["Question1"] = box1.Text;
                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I need to keep the selection of radio button for every row I have created.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the "+" button to trigger an event on the client side instead of posting to the server for a new row.  You could then just loop through the collection when you post it to your "Save" event handler on the server.

Currently what seems to be happening is a postback from you hitting the "+" button.  A postback would result in the clearing of those radio buttons.  I see you're trying to retain the status via the ViewState but you're saving the checked status for the same ViewState property.

See the difference in the code below.

```
    if (radiobtn1.Checked == true)
    {
        ViewState["RadioButtonStatus"] = radiobtn1.Checked;
    }

    if (radiobtn2.Checked == true)
    {
        ViewState["DifferentRadioButtonStatus"] = radiobtn2.Checked;
    }
```

Here are some updates to your AddNewRow method.  There's a lot of stuff going on here, this may be a little bit over engineered.  Hope it helps you move towards the right direction.

```
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

            var drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);

        // Updated from > 0 to > 1 since the first action you're taking is in GridView1.Rows[1] via the for loop below
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Question"] = box1.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Hints No.1"] = box2.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Hints No.2"] = box3.Text;

                rowIndex++;
            }


            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    //  Set Previous Data on Postbacks
    SetPreviousData();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks , but how do i display the viewstate on page load (!page.ispostback) ? .... i tried but it always ended up null

Comment: If there's no postback I would expect it to be null.  In the page load you shouldn't need to access those properties, null would mean neither  radio buttons are selected.

Comment: yes but i cant even run the page now , error with if statement is always null because no buttons is being selected but how am i going to solve this ...

Comment: I'd need to see what your page load is doing to make any more suggestions.  Can you edit your question above to include it?

Comment: updated , theres nothing in pageload cos i keep getting null errors so i removed it

Comment: I'd highly recommend taking the Javascript/JQuery approach to adding these rows.  I'm looking into the alternate solution right now.

Comment: hi i have seen your updated codes and tried it , but theres a null exception at the loop.